# paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to server with paramiko but there's always some kind of problem with private key. id_dsa is an open ssh key, so I don't know what the problem can be.

Thanks in advance!

```
   import paramiko
   k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("C:/Users/bok/Desktop/id_dsa")

   c = paramiko.SSHClient()
   c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   print ("connecting")
   c.connect( hostname = "3x.1x9.2x.2x", username = "taq4", password = "xxxxxx", pkey=k)
   print ("connected")
   commands = [ "ls", "pwd" ]
   for command in commands:
           print ("Executing {}").format( command )
           stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
           print(stdout.read())
           print("Errors")
           print(stderr.read())
   c.close()
```

error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
```

Comment: Providing info about your use case always helps, good luck!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572165/uploading-file-to-google-cloud-server-in-python thanks

Answer (score 3):

It was your RSA key gen with password, just try it with your password
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(rsa_key, password)

Comment: more info could see this http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/ssh_exception.html

Comment: Doing this way, then I get `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: no lines in RSA private key file`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error above:

`paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: private key file is encrypted`

But it worked fine (passwordless) with `ssh -i <key_filename> ...`

##### Turns out my call to `.connect()` was simply missing the [non-standard] port#

```py
    first_hop = {
        "hostname": "mydomain.ca",
        "username": "myuser",
        "pkey": Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(f"cell.key"),
        # "pkey": Ed25519Key.from_private_key(open("cell.key")),
        "port": 2222
    }
    ssh.connect(**first_hop)
```